# git keeps pushing commits that it isn't supposed to

Tags: git, github

```
$ git log
commit 87da9 (HEAD -> master)
Author: me
Date:   Tue Mar 8 11:34:10 2022 +0100

    .gitignore added

commit 2cdaf
Author: me
Date:   Tue Mar 8 01:16:09 2022 +0100

    First commit
```

First commit was a mistake and contains a large file. Then, after adding `.gitignore` that blocks the file and a
directory where it was extracted

```
$ cat .gitignore 
Big\ File/**
Big\ File.zip
```

Then `.gitignore` was refreshed:

```
$ git rm -r --cached .
...

$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        deleted:    .gitignore
        deleted:    File 1.doc
        deleted:    Big\ File.zip
...
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        .gitignore
        File 1.doc
        Good File 1.pdf
        Good File 2.txt
```

after the refresh files were readded:

```
$ git add -A
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in .gitignore.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
```

then a new commit was made:

```
$ git commit -m ".gitignore refreshed"
[master c8a6f46] .gitignore refreshed
 30 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 delete mode 100644 Big\ File.zip
```

Everything looks ok (all unneeded files were removed).

```
$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean

$ git log
commit c8a6f (HEAD -> master)
Author: me
Date:   Tue Mar 8 11:46:57 2022 +0100

    .gitignore refreshed

commit 87da9
Author: me
Date:   Tue Mar 8 11:34:10 2022 +0100

    .gitignore added

commit 2cdaf
Author: me
Date:   Tue Mar 8 01:16:09 2022 +0100

    First commit
```

The last commit is not really needed so:

```
$ git reset --soft 87da9
```

The first commit might be needed at some point -> push only the second:

```
$ git push -f -u origin 87da9:refs/heads/master
```

Looks good, but git thinks it's better to push the first commit as well for some reason and ends up running  into the 100MB size limit on github.

How can git be told **NOT** to push the first commit?

Comment: You cannot pick and select individual commits to push. You always push all history that leads up to the selected commit. Usually, the parts of the history that the destination already knows about are not pushed, but you seem to do your first ever push to that remote, so there is nothing to skip.

Comment: Sure, you can rewrite the history. For example with `git rebase`. But since yours is so short, it is probably much easier to just rebuild the few commits that you need in the way you need them.

Comment: @j6t done; added an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked:

```
# move master into another branch
$ git branch -m master old_master
# check 
$ git branch
* old_master
# create a new separate branch separate from the old one
$ git checkout --orphan master
Switched to a new branch 'master'
# rm old branch 
$ git branch -D old_master
Deleted branch old_master (was 2cdaf8a).
# update HEAD to point to it
$ git update-ref -d HEAD
# check
$ git log
fatal: your current branch 'master' does not have any commits yet
# clear cache if needed
$ git rm -r --cached .
# add everything
$ git add .
# commit
$ git commit -m "new branch with fresh history and no big files"
# push 
$ git push -u origin master
```

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, because the story is super short and you cannot reset to the "zero commit" because the first commit was the one considered as wrong, I suggest you to:

```
rm -rf .git
git remote add origin <your.remote.repo.url>
git commit -am "very first commit"
git push -f origin main
```

Comment: Wanted to do it in pure git